# How to install LAMP where M=Mysql?

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp

I want to setup LAMP  (M=Mysql). I am following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

The installation command given is: `sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2`

Looking at the above command, the db technology seems to be mariadb. So does this include mysql or is there a separate command to install mysql?

Comment: As the first line of that documentation tells you: "Apache web server with PHP and MariaDB (**a community-developed fork of MySQL**)"

Comment: You can't really expect newcomers to know each and every term in each and every doc now, can you? :D 

It's a common thing, once the lad starts coding, they'll figure this all out.

Comment: I actually understand that MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. What is confusing to me is that I am looking to specifically install MySQL and not any of its fork. Is this possible? or what I am asking for is irrelevant because MariaDB is the accepted MySQL standard version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB is essentially MySQL, you won't need to install anything else.

When accessing the database through a terminal you use the `mysql user@host` command and almost all framework configurations will have you list it as MySQL, though you should confirm this with the documentation of whatever you are using.

All in all you should be all set.

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, feel free to mark it as the correct answer so this question is helpful for other people :D